# NeoVim shows diagnostic for `std` and other crates outside my current workspace

Tags: rust, neovim, language-server-protocol, rust-analyzer

I use NeoVim with `LSP Zero` plugin + `Rust analyzer` for rust programming.

When I jump to a definition in some external crate (including `std`) Nvim's diagnostic starts to show me all the errors from that crate.

For example, if I just create new project via `cargo init some_project`, then open it via `nvim some_project` and jump to the definition of `println` macro, diagnostic starts to show me tons of this:

```
/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/lib.rs|100 col 1-32 error| `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/lib.rs|100 col 12-30 error| `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/lib.rs|101 col 12-30 error| `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
```

Also I tried use `CoC` instead of native LSP, but it doesn't change anything.

What is correct way to disable diagnostic for crates outside my current workspace?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found solution for this issue.

We need to specify custom `root_dir` function when configuring LSP with `Rust Analyzer`:

```lua
local util = require('lspconfig.util')

local rustPorjectDir = nil -- caches current project dir
local rustRootPattern = util.root_pattern("Cargo.toml", "rust-project.json") -- default `root_dir` implementation

local function rust_root_dir(fname)
    local function get()
        rustPorjectDir = rustRootPattern(fname)
        return rustPorjectDir
    end

    return rustPorjectDir or get()
end
```